# Google chart control values to asp variable

Tags: asp-classic, google-visualization

I have a Google-Graph with a range-slider control that I want to use to generate a file. I have ASP code for file generation so that's most of the work already done.

What I want to be able to do is read the 'start' and 'end' values from the range-slider and use those values to generate a file with only data in the range. So ultimately what I need is a way to read and store the range as an ASP variable.

Please note that this is 'ASP' not 'ASP.Net' (this was not my decision and can not be changed at this point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to pass a set of values back to the server (AJAX and forms are two of the more common ones).  You can get the start and end of the range by calling the filter's `getState` method:

```
var state = filter.getState();
```

If you are using a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter), the state has a `range` property with `start` and `end` properties:

```
var start = state.range.start;
var end = state.range.end;
```

If you are using a [NumberRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#numberrangefilter) or [DateRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#daterangefilter), `state` will have `lowValue` and `highValue` properties (plus a `lowThumbAtMinimum` and `highThumbAtMinimum`, which are probably not relevant to your needs):

```
var start = state.lowValue;
var end = state.highValue;
```

The data type of the values will be the same as the column they are filtering on (if you are filtering a "number" column, they are numbers; if you are filtering a "date" or "datetime" column, they are Date objects).

Use whatever method you choose to pass those values back to the server.